# Картинка идёт поверх другого блока

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, при transform:scale(1.1) картинка идёт поверх другого блока,  как это исправить? Эта картинка находиться в обёрточном блоке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, вы увеличиваете размеры блока на `1.1`. Т.е. фактически для всех других элементов он остался как и был, потому что свойство `transition: scale(n);` никак не влияет на вашу верстку, вы просто увеличили элемент в результате чего он будет налазить на другие элементы визуально.

А если это важно, то скиньте ваш `html` и `css`, посмотрим.

Comment: @Cтанислав Кремса, спасибо, не важно, просто хотел поексперементировать, еще раз спасибо

Comment: @CR7 прошу, обращайтесь

Comment: скиньте пожалуйста свой телеграм или же инстаграм, буду оращатся за советами, если можно

Comment: Просто создавайте здесь тему и я и не только я, будем отвечать на все ваши вопросы.

Comment: Если ответ вас удовлетворил, отметьте его галочкой чтоб другие пользователи могли ориентироваться в вашем вопросе.